# Select NULL from empty XML element in XML variable

Tags: xml, t-sql

What's the best way to select null from empty XML Node ?

E.g.

```
DECLARE @xml xml = N'<t />'
SELECT @xml.value('(t)[1]','int')
```

This will return 0 instead of NULL. Why ? How to extract null?

Answer (score 3):

An empty element does not have a `text()`. Try this:

```
DECLARE @xml xml = N'<t />'
SELECT @xml.value('(t/text())[1]','int');
```

### UPDATE Some explanation

XML uses a **defined string format** for each datatype. As you surely know, an `INT` is not stored as a chain of digits, but as a binary value internally. What you see in a resultset and what is generated into an `XML` is a **string representation** for human readers following certain rules to ensure correct reading. Date and time values should be ISO8601, BLOBs are converted to `base64` and so on...

Each datatype has a default value, with `INT` this is `0`. Try this, it's the same without XML:

```
SELECT CAST('' AS INT)     --returns 0
      ,CAST(NULL AS INT)   --returns NULL
```

There is no `NULL` value in XML (well, you can specify `XSINIL` to use a marking attribute), but elements can be missing. Only missing elements are read as `NULL`...

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32985478/5089204) for some examples about `NULL` and `empty`. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43242238/5089204) to understand more about `text()`

Answer (score 0):

I found also this function:

```
DECLARE @xml xml = N'<t />'
SELECT @xml.query('/t').value('number(.)','int')
```

But I was wondering if there is, a way without using inner function. Maybe some namespace.

Comment: You are thinking to complicated... No need for `query()`, this does not help at all and has nothing to do with the issue... You'd get the same with `SELECT @xml.value('number(.)','int')` or with `SELECT @xml.value('number(/t[1])','int')`. This is bound to the usage of `number()`. Please read my updated answer for further details.