# Manipulate XMLNamespaces

Tags: sql-server, xml, xpath, namespaces

I have the following output from SQL using `FOR XML` clause:

```
<q17:DestinationSection xmlns:q17="http://ITrack.Transmission/2011/02/25/Objects">
<q17:DestinationCode>1</q17:DestinationCode>
<q17:DestinationName>Strada Rampei 9, Iasi</q17:DestinationName>
<q17:DestinationAddress1>Strada Rampei 9, Iasi</q17:DestinationAddress1>
<q17:DestinationAddress2>
xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
</q17:DestinationAddress2>
</q17:DestinationSection>
```

The DestinationSection is the main root for this block of data. Is there any possibility to do some workaround and to have something like below in the `<q17:DestinationAddress2></q17:DestinationAddress2>` tag?

```
<q17:DestinationAddress2 xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"</q17:DestinationAddress2>
```

I have tried something but I get an error that says that I need to declare the namespace but I really don't know where to "introduce" that definition.

**My SQL statement**

```
DECLARE @XMLFINAL VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @XMLFINAL=''
DECLARE @XMLFINAL2 VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @XMLFINAL2=''
DECLARE @NUMBER NVARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @NUMBER2 NVARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @XML VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @XML2 VARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE Rec CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR

SELECT  GID FROM PurchaseDocumentsHeader

OPEN Rec
FETCH NEXT FROM Rec INTO @NUMBER2
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN
SET @XML2=''    


;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://ITrack.Transmission/2011/02/25/Objects' as q17)


SELECT @XML2= (

SELECT 
DestCode AS 'q17:DestinationCode', DestDescr 'q17:DestinationName', DestAddr AS 'q17:DestinationAddress1', DestAddr2 AS 'q17:DestinationAddress2',
DestZIP AS 'q17:DestinationZIP'

FROM PurchaseDocumentsHeader WHERE GID=@NUMBER2
FOR XML RAW('q17:DestinationSection'),ELEMENTS
)

FETCH NEXT FROM Rec INTO @NUMBER2

SET @XMLFINAL2=@XMLFINAL2+@XML2
END

CLOSE Rec DEALLOCATE Rec
```

**EDIT**

Please find below my DDL. It's a view used to extract the data from an official table.

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[PurchaseDocumentsHeader]
AS
SELECT esd.GID, esd.ADRegistrationDate, esgo.Code AS DestCode, esgo.Description AS DestDescr, esgo.Address1 AS DestAddr, esgo.fCityCode AS DestCity,
 esgp.TaxRegistrationNumber AS DestZIP, 'xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"' AS DestAddr2, esgo.Description AS DestRomanized,
 esgo.Address1 AS DestAddress1Romanized, 
 'xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"' AS DestAddress2Romanized,  esgp.TaxRegistrationNumber AS DestZIPRom,  
 esgo.fCityCode AS DestCityRomanized, esgo.fCountryCode AS DestCountry, cast('DestinationGLN xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>' AS XML) AS DestGLN, 
 'xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"' AS DestCoord
FROM ESFIDocumentTrade esd
LEFT JOIN ESGOSites esgo on esd.fDeliverySiteGID=esgo.GID
LEFT JOIN ESFITradeAccount esc on esd.fTradeAccountGID=esc.GID
LEFT JOIN ESGOPerson esgp on esc.fPersonCodeGID=esgo.GID
LEFT JOIN ESFIDocumentType est on esd.fADDocumentTypeGID=est.GID
WHERE esd.fTransitionStepCode='APPROVED' AND est.Code='CVR'
AND YEAR(esd.ADRegistrationDate)=YEAR(GETDATE())
AND MONTH(esd.ADRegistrationDate)=MONTH(GETDATE())
AND DAY(esd.ADRegistrationDate)=DAY(GETDATE())

GO
```

**Later edit**

```
CREATE TABLE DocPurcharseHeader
(
ADRegistrationDate date,
Code NVARCHAR(4000),
Description NVARCHAR(4000),
Address1 NVARCHAR (4000),
Address2 NVARCHAR (4000),
City NVARCHAR (4000),
ZIPCode NVARCHAR(4000)
)

INSERT INTO DocPurcharseHeader (ADRegistrationDate, Code, Description, Address1, Address2, City, ZIPCode)
VALUES('2017-10-16', '01', 'MyPOS', 'MyPOSAddress1', 'MyPOSAddress2', 'BUCHAREST', '123456')
```

**2nd Later edit**

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://ITrack.Transmission/2011/02/25/Objects' as q17)

    SELECT @XMLSalesOrders=(
    SELECT DestCode AS [q17:DestinationCode]
          ,DestDescr AS [q17:DestinationName]
          ,DestAddr AS [q17:DestinationAddress1]
          ,DestAddr2 AS [q17:DestinationAddress2]
    FROM PurchaseDocumentsHeader
    FOR XML PATH('q17:DestinationSection'),ELEMENTS XSINIL,ROOT('q17:DestinationSections'))
```

This code above is generating the below output, without `XSINL` directive:

```
<q17:DestinationSections xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:q17="http://ITrack.Transmission/2011/02/25/Objects">
<q17:DestinationSection>
<q17:DestinationCode>1</q17:DestinationCode>
<q17:DestinationName>Strada Rampei 9, Iasi</q17:DestinationName>
<q17:DestinationAddress1>Strada Rampei 9, Iasi</q17:DestinationAddress1>
<q17:DestinationAddress2/>
</q17:DestinationSection>
<q17:DestinationSection>
```

Comment: You need to post sample DDL, sample data and select from that.  We do not have your DDL or sample data.  Example;  CREATE TABLE #SampleData
 ( 
  [MyId] int,
  [MyString] nvarchar(40)
 )

 INSERT INTO #SampleData (MyId, MyString) select 1 , 'One' union all select 2, 'Two'

 Select * from #SampleData

 DROP TABLE #SampleData

Comment: @granadaCoder - done.

Comment: @granadaCoder - this is not my ultimate view, it's my actual trying to find a solution and I kept modifying it and modifying it. If needed, I can modify the view.

Comment: Showing us the definition if your View is NOT posting the DDL with sample data.  I provided a sample/example on how to create example DDL and put data into it.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @granadaCoder - is it ok now?

Comment: I (or anyone) should be able to highlight your code, paste into my SSMS query window and run it with no errors.  After that works, you would say "I am getting the below but I am expecting or trying to get something else" and list what that something else is.

Comment: @granadaCoder - understood.

Comment: Hi cdrrrrr, I saw, that you've tried to place an edit to my answer with "My output", which was rejected (correctly)... This is not the way the edit options of an answer ist meant to be used... What is your issue? Edit your question or place a comment... Could you reproduce my answer using my code? Is your problem solved?

Comment: @Shnugo - I've edited my post. My `<DestinationAddress2>` tag is not generated as it should be according to your suggestion.

Comment: @Shnugo - is there any way to send you a PM on this website?

Comment: @cdrrrrr, Well, there is an eMail within the description on my developer story (you find it with my profile), but this is against the idea of SO. Any question should be asked and answered publicly to help others searching for similar issues... See my answer for another update

Comment: @Shnugo - I understood what you have said and it's working fine now, as you explained. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are trying to out-trick the very mighty XML engine.

As stated in your other question:

**Never do this in a `CURSOR`!** They are bad and evil, coming directly of the hell of procedural thinking and were invented by the devil of spaghetti code...

Try it like this:

I use your table DDL an insert some data. The second row will have a `NULL` in address2. Normally XML will simply omit NULL values. A not existing node is read as a `NULL` value. But you can force `NULL`s to be introduced as `xsi.nil="true"` with `ELEMENTS XSINIL`:

```
CREATE TABLE DocPurcharseHeader
(
ADRegistrationDate date,
Code NVARCHAR(4000),
Description NVARCHAR(4000),
Address1 NVARCHAR (4000),
Address2 NVARCHAR (4000),
City NVARCHAR (4000),
ZIPCode NVARCHAR(4000)  
);

INSERT INTO DocPurcharseHeader (ADRegistrationDate, Code, Description, Address1, Address2, City, ZIPCode)
VALUES('2017-10-16', '01', 'MyPOS', 'MyPOSAddress1', 'MyPOSAddress2', 'BUCHAREST', '123456')
     ,('2017-10-16', '01', 'MyPOS', 'MyPOSAddress1', NULL, 'BUCHAREST', '123456');

WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://ITrack.Transmission/2011/02/25/Objects' AS q17)
SELECT Code AS [q17:DestinationCode]
      ,Description AS [q17:DestinationName]
      ,Address1 AS [q17:DestinationAddress1]
      ,Address2 AS [q17:DestinationAddress2]
FROM DocPurcharseHeader
FOR XML PATH('q17:DestinationSection'),ELEMENTS XSINIL,ROOT('q17:DestinationSections');
```

The result

```
<q17:DestinationSections xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:q17="http://ITrack.Transmission/2011/02/25/Objects">
  <q17:DestinationSection>
    <q17:DestinationCode>01</q17:DestinationCode>
    <q17:DestinationName>MyPOS</q17:DestinationName>
    <q17:DestinationAddress1>MyPOSAddress1</q17:DestinationAddress1>
    <q17:DestinationAddress2>MyPOSAddress2</q17:DestinationAddress2>
  </q17:DestinationSection>
  <q17:DestinationSection>
    <q17:DestinationCode>01</q17:DestinationCode>
    <q17:DestinationName>MyPOS</q17:DestinationName>
    <q17:DestinationAddress1>MyPOSAddress1</q17:DestinationAddress1>
    <q17:DestinationAddress2 xsi:nil="true" />
  </q17:DestinationSection>
</q17:DestinationSections>
```

### UPDATE: About `NULL` values:

Try this

```
DECLARE @DummyTable TABLE(SomeDescription VARCHAR(500), SomeValue VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @DummyTable VALUES('A real NULL value',NULL)
                             ,('An empty string','')
                             ,('A blank string','   ')
                             ,('Some Text','blah blah');

WITH XMLNAMESPACES('SomeURL' AS q17)
SELECT SomeDescription AS [q17:Description]
      ,SomeValue AS [q17:Value]
FROM @DummyTable                
FOR XML PATH('q17:row'),ELEMENTS XSINIL,ROOT('root');
```

To get this

```
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:q17="SomeURL">
  <q17:row>
    <q17:Description>A real NULL value</q17:Description>
    <q17:Value xsi:nil="true" />
  </q17:row>
  <q17:row>
    <q17:Description>An empty string</q17:Description>
    <q17:Value></q17:Value>
  </q17:row>
  <q17:row>
    <q17:Description>A blank string</q17:Description>
    <q17:Value>   </q17:Value>
  </q17:row>
  <q17:row>
    <q17:Description>Some Text</q17:Description>
    <q17:Value>blah blah</q17:Value>
  </q17:row>
</root>
```

You can see, that the **real NULL** is encoded as `xsi:nil="true"`, while the empty string is shown as `<q17:Value></q17:Value>` (which is exactly the same as `<q17:Value />`).

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32985478/5089204) for some examples about `NULL` and `empty`. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43242238/5089204) to understand more about `text()`

Comment: Oh, I've been to hell and came back :-). Sometimes, there's just no way around it (but in this case, there is).